# getting error for d3 Js

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am creating bar chart using D3 Js within Angular 2 application.

I am using **V4.4 of D3** and getting below error at below line,

**.domain(d3.range(n))**

```
 var n = 20, // number of samples
        m = 4; // number of series

    var data = d3.range(m).map(function () { return d3.range(n).map(Math.random); });

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(d3.range(n))
        .range([0, width], .2);

    var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(d3.range(m))
        .range([0, x0.range()]);

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Error,

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that `d3.scaleBand().domain` wants an array of strings as an argument, you are giving it an array of numbers.  Just coerce your numbers to strings like:

```
 d3.scaleBand()
   .domain(d3.range(N).map((d) => d+""))
   .range([0, width], .2);
```